# Automatically generate comment at close vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When I cast a duplicate close vote on a question, the system automatically generates a comment (I vote to close the question being duplicate of ...)

I think it's very useful as it gives an early warning for the owner; I'm also doing something similar with other type of close votes, explaining what's wrong with the question.

Is it possible to have this automatic comment for other type of votes too?

Comment: ooooor just post a comment manually. I was doing that for years, and still do so.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I know and I do it too, but it increase the time I (waste) spend on low quality questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a Stack App for that!

[AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) is available for Chrome and Firefox, and also as a userscript. You can set custom pro forma comments and then easily insert them with a couple clicks using the `auto` link it places under the Add Comment button. It has some other neat features too, like letting you mark a pro forma comment as only for questions or answers, or as applicable to all posts.

Comment: Just to add, it comes with some canned text, but you can modify it and add to it.  So if you really like a comment someone else has perfected, you can steal it and automate it for yourself.  :-)  You can also customize the text for a specific post after you insert it.